# Retrive an object from json string using JSON_QUERY in oracle

Tags: sql, json, oracle

Below the code which I'm trying but getting null value.

```
SELECT json_query(object_data,'$.AOF.LEAD_DATA.DIRECTOR[*]')
FROM TB_COP_BUSS_OBJ_TXN FD,
JSON_TABLE(FD.OBJECT_DATA,'$.AOF.LEAD_DATA.DIRECTOR[*]' columns
( AUS_FLAG  VARCHAR2(40) PATH '$.CHECKBOX.AUS_FLAG.value')) j
WHERE FD.OBJECT_PRI_KEY_1 = 'XXXXXXX' and j.AUS_FLAG ='Y'
```

I'm trying to get full data which is inside director object/array. when I'm using 0,1,2, instead of * then I'm getting the data but I need to check aus flag and need those index data of that array object. please help

please help.

Comment: Please post the source data. How should we guess the reason of null?

Comment: When I'm using 0 or 1 or 2 index number instead of * then I'm getting the data.

Comment: [{"RELATION_TYPE":{"CODE":1,"VALUE":"PARTNER","code":1,"value":"PARTNER"},"TITLE":{"CODE":"1","VALUE":"MR.","code":"1","value":"MR."},"DOB":"2022-06-08","AGE":"0","GENDER":{"CODE":"1","VALUE":"MALE","code":"1","value":"MALE"},"NATIONALITY":{"CODE":"1","VALUE":"INDIAN","code":"1","value":"INDIAN"},"IS_BENEFITIAL_OWNER":"No"},{"RELATION_TYPE":{"CODE":2,"VALUE":"DIRECTOR","code":2,"value":"DIRECTOR"},"GENDER":{"CODE":"1","VALUE":"MALE","code":"1","value":"MALE"},"TITLE":{"CODE":"1","VALUE":"MR.","code":"1","value":"MR."},"edit_flag":"N","DIRECTOR_ID":"C402577","IS_BENEFITIAL_OWNER":"No"}]

Comment: Your data does not have an `AOF` key in the root object (and the root is an array and not an object); of course it is not going to return anything.

Comment: I can't post the ceomplete data here due to character limits. the source data has everything and instead using * when I'm using index value like 0,1,2 then I'm getting the data.

Comment: For eg. u can refer this {"employees":[{"name":"Raj","email":"raj@gmail.com","age":32},{"name":"Mohan","email":"Mohan@yahoo.com","age":21}]}

Comment: Do not post code/data in comments and do not post 50 lines of data when 2 will be a sufficient example. [edit] your answer and include a [MRE] with; the `CREATE TABLE` statement for your table; the `INSERT`  statements for some **MINIMAL** sample data; and the expected output for that sample data.

Comment: @MT0 can you please help

Comment: That depends, can you [edit] your question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` statement for your table; the `INSERT` statements for some **MINIMAL** sample data; and the expected output for that sample data. If you can then you will probably find someone who can help; if you cannot then we are left trying to guess what the input and output is and then when you tell us "Thanks . but I'm not getting data using this" we're left in an unconstructive position where we do not have the information to be able to help you. So help us to help you and give us the necessary information.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE TB_COP_BUSS_OBJ_TXN (
  OBJECT_PRI_KEY_1 VARCHAR2(20) PRIMARY KEY,
  OBJECT_DATA CLOB CHECK (OBJECT_DATA IS JSON)
);

INSERT INTO TB_COP_BUSS_OBJ_TXN (
  OBJECT_PRI_KEY_1,
  OBJECT_DATA
) VALUES (
  'XXXXXX',
  '{"AOF":{"LEAD_DATA":{"DIRECTOR":[1,2,3]}}}'
);
```

Then you can use:

```sql
SELECT JSON_QUERY(OBJECT_DATA,'$.AOF.LEAD_DATA."DIRECTOR"')
from   TB_COP_BUSS_OBJ_TXN FD
WHERE  OBJECT_PRI_KEY_1 = 'XXXXXX'
```

Which outputs:

> | JSON_QUERY(OBJECT_DATA,'$.AOF.LEAD_DATA."DIRECTOR"') |
> | --- |
> | [1,2,3] |

Or you can use:

```sql
SELECT value
from   TB_COP_BUSS_OBJ_TXN FD
       CROSS APPLY JSON_TABLE(
         fd.object_data,
         '$.AOF.LEAD_DATA."DIRECTOR"[*]'
         COLUMNS (
           value NUMBER PATH '$'
         )
       )
WHERE  OBJECT_PRI_KEY_1 = 'XXXXXX'
```

Which outputs:

> | VALUE |
> | --- |
> | 1 |
> | 2 |
> | 3 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=e8ca0c1f1a33fd7e132a62246531cf0e)*

Comment: Thanks . but I'm not getting data using this . please see the source data in above comment.